# iOS 10 ATS error: cannot connect to my recently SSL protected server "tls_handshake_process: [-9824]"

Tags: ssl, ios10, handshake, app-transport-security

I'm not able to make requests to my server. I've place some json files that i want to access. Requests to other SSL secured sites, such as https://httpbin.org/get do work. Accessing the json file through the browser does work as expected.

## My certificate

(TLS 1.2), an obsolete key exchange (RSA), and a strong cipher (AES_128_GCM).

## Test code

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/file.json")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                print(jsonObject)
            } catch {
                print("serialization error: \n",error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()
```

## Error

```
2017-01-26 08:20:04.303569 jsonOnlineTest[3200:1889903] [] nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9824]
2017-01-26 08:20:04.304558 jsonOnlineTest[3200:1889926] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x170056590 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
```

Comment: Martin Ueding, thanks for editing and shortening my error message. But do you know more about this subject? Thanks in advance

Comment: Any update on this issue ? Could you make it work without changing anything on the server  ?

Comment: I called my server provider and they confirmed that their ssl should be ok with apple. So i just accepted http through the plist. I will call apple on this and let you know..